# qtcreator doesn't launch on ubunu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, qt

I don't know why it doesn't launch. The last time I used it, it was perfect. I tried to run it using the terminal, then it gives:

```
Bus error (core dumped)
```

I tried to update and upgrade, then tried to install these libs too:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install libqt5dbus5 libqt5widgets5 libqt5network5 libqt5gui5 libqt5core5a libdouble-conversion libxcb-xinerama0
```

But this did not fix the problem.

I used `export QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1` before launching it and the last part was

```
Got keys from plugin meta data ("webp")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/home/asmmo/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/bin/imageformats" ...
loaded library "/home/asmmo/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/lib/Qt/plugins/imageformats/libqgif.so"
loaded library "/home/asmmo/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/lib/Qt/plugins/imageformats/libqicns.so"
loaded library "/home/asmmo/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/lib/Qt/plugins/imageformats/libqico.so"
loaded library "/home/asmmo/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/lib/Qt/plugins/imageformats/libqjpeg.so"
loaded library "/home/asmmo/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/lib/Qt/plugins/imageformats/libqsvg.so"
loaded library "/home/asmmo/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/lib/Qt/plugins/imageformats/libqtga.so"
loaded library "/home/asmmo/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/lib/Qt/plugins/imageformats/libqtiff.so"
loaded library "/home/asmmo/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/lib/Qt/plugins/imageformats/libqwbmp.so"
Bus error (core dumped)
```

Comment: When was the last time that you used Qt Creator? Was it on a previous version of Ubuntu?

Comment: @Matigo no at all. It was in the same day. just after restarting the machine

Comment: Have you modified LD_LIBRARY_PATH? Why qtcreator lists stuff from /home/asmmo/Qt on start?

Answer (score 0):

The "bus error" message does not happen very often but, if you are trying to re-install Qt Creator, you may want to cleanly remove it, then reinstall.

You can check to see which QT packages are installed with this:

```
dpkg -l | grep qt | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -n1 echo
```

Not everything can be removed, nor should it be necessary to do so, but focusing on the items prefixed with `qt5` should be enough:

```
sudo apt remove --purge qt5*
sudo apt autoremove
```

Now you can reinstall:

```
sudo apt install build-essential
sudo apt install qtcreator qt5-default
```

If you receive a "Cannot overwrite file ..." error after re-installing, you will need to clear the `/home/{user}/.config/` directory of anything starting with the letters `QT`. Be sure to change `{user}` to your account name.

Hope this resolves your issue.